# Why is my "or" statement not working as I want?

Tags: python

```
import time

repeat=0
price=0
print("Welcome to McDonald's self order system")
time.sleep(0.5)
name_person=str(input("\nPlease enter your name to continue: "))
while True:
    order=int(input("\n---Menu---\n 1.Burger\n 2.McPuff\n 3.Ice Cream\n 4.Cold Drink\n\nPlease order by typing the number: "))
    if order in range(1,4) :
        repeat=str(input("Do you want to order more? Yes/No: "))
        if repeat == "No" or "no":
            print("Ok")
            break
    else :
        print("\n!!Invalid input!!")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

The `or` command is not working when I am typing **`No`** it shows `Ok` that's normal but if I type **`Yes`** it should loop but then also it's showing `Ok` and when I am typing anything it's giving the output `Ok` but if I am removing the `or` its working perfectly.

Comment: That's not how `or` works. `or` is for values where one value may be empty or not exist so you add an `or` after it for a known value that does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `if repeat == "No" or "no"`, use:

```py
if repeat == "No" or repeat == "no"
```

Or even:

```py
if repeat in ("No", "no")
```

Comment: No need to answer this when there are two direct duplicates posted in the comments.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Compare this answer to the accepted one in the [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20002504/669576). This one contains a fraction of the information. It's a distraction. OP should be directed to the best answer - which is not this one.